# How to handle bindable application wide variables in a WPF MVVM application?

Tags: wpf, variables, mvvm, desktop-application

I am writing a fairly large scale WPF desktop application using the MVVM pattern. I have been stuck for a while on getting my common properties to update in a View other than the one that updated it.

I have a `RibbonWindow MainView` that contains a `ContentControl` that displays the remaining Views one at a time dependant on the user's selection. I have a `BaseViewModel` class that all the ViewModels extend. Among other things, this class exposes the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and contains a `static` property of type `CommonDataStore`. This class also implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and contains the properties that are to be available to every ViewModel.

Now, although I can access and successfully update the `CommonDataStore` properties from any ViewModel, the problem is that the WPF Framework will only notify properties that have changed in the current View. Therefore, although the common values have been updated in other ViewModels, their associated Views do not get updated.

One example from my application is the login screen: As the user logs in, my LogInView updates with the new information (ie. full name) from the database, but the user details in the MainView do not.

After reading a few other posts, I also tried implementing the `CommonDataStore` class as a Singleton, but that didn't help. I could also just pass a reference to this common data object to the constructor of each ViewModel from the `MainViewModel`, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

I have also discovered that in WPF, `static` properties are treated a bit like constant values. It seems that they just read the value once.

So anyway it's clear, my attempts have all failed. I was wondering what the standard way of doing this was? In particular, I need to be able to bind to the common properties and have all of my ViewModels and Views update when any common value is changed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Edit >> Really? No one uses application wide variables in an MVVM WPF application?

I have now removed the static part of the Common property declaration and am simply passing a copy into each ViewModel individually. This seems to work, but I'd really like to know how others approach this situation. Please answer by simply letting me know how you organise this application wide data.

Comment: Post some code please... How did you write the bindings?

Comment: In the usual way: `Text="{Binding Common.CurrentEmployee.Name}"`. `Common` is the property in the Base class and 'CurrentEmployee' is a propetry in the `CommonDataStore` class. I can't post all my related code - there's far too much. I'm asking how other people achieve this, not asking for my code to be fixed specifically.

Comment: OK, but is Common shared among all instances of the base class?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you binding with Mode=TwoWay? Do your model objects implement INotify? Or just the properties in your VM?

Comment: The `Common` property is `static` so yes, it's shared amongst all ViewModels. There is no need for `Two-Way` binding in my Views... logging in uses a `Command` that calls a method in the `LogInViewModel`. That method logs the user in and retrieves the user details from the database. It updates the Common object, but only the `LogInView` is updated with the details. All properties in the `CommonDataStore` call the `INotifyPropertyChanged` system, but the `Common` property in the `BaseViewModel` cannot because it's static. I also wrapped it in a non static method that did call Notify... no help.

Comment: You are going to need to post some code examples or this will be a need in a haystack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar to what you describe last. I have class called SecurityContext that holds some of the application-wide data. One instance is created when the application starts up and then that instance is passed into the constructors of all the ViewModels through dependency-injection. I have a base class for ViewModels which exposes that object through a regular instance property (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike. I was glad to get some feedback that what I was doing wasn't against any MVVM principles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into implementing the Observer Pattern?  We have done so with [IObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) and [IObserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx).  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362412%28SQL.105%29.aspx) describes the "IObservable/IObserver Development Model" as follows:

The IObservable/IObserver development model provides an alternative to using input and output adapters as the producer and consumer of event sources and sinks. This model is based on the IObservable/IObserver design pattern in which an observer is any object that wishes to be notified when the state of another object changes, and an observable is any object whose state may be of interest, and in whom another object may register an interest. For example, in a publication-subscription application, the observable is the publisher, and the observer is the subscriber object. For more information, see Exploring the Observer Design Pattern on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although interesting, I think that the Observer pattern is not what I am after.